# how to find allocated memory by a variable?

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows

```
class app {
        public int x = 3; 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
}
```

it's possible get the memory address allocated by `x` variable?

the example can be in `C`, `C++`, `C#` or `D`.
I hope it is clear
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ampersand (`&`) is the "address-of" operator in most C-like languages:

```
int x;
printf("Address of x is %p\n", &x);
```

The return value of `&` is effectively a [pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) to its operand.

Comment: Anyone downvoting care to be a bit more verbose? My answer is not incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

In C and in C++ this is fairly straight-forward. I'll give the example in C++:

```
struct App
{
   int x;
   App() : x(3) { }
};

int main()
{
  App a;
  int * p = &a.x; // address goes here
}
```

There is of course no such thing as "the variable `App::x`", since `App` is only the *type*. Each *instance* of this type, such as `a` in the example, carries its own set of member variables, and a pointer to the member variable is readily obtained. (The same is true for plain data structs in C.)

<sub>Note that C++ has another, related feature: Member pointers. This allows us to form the opaque value `int App::*pm = &App::x` which by itself doesn't point to anything, but only carries information about the *offset* of `App::x` inside the class, if you will. This animal can be used *together with an instance* to obtain the actual value, e.g. `a.*pm`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Skipping D and E. C# and F# (and other CLR languages) - there is no fixed addres for any partcular variable in general. One can use managed debugger (i.e. WinDbg + SOS) to find address of any particular variable, or use `fixed` along with interop classes.

Comment: addition: fixed is only required when the variable resides on the heap. doing a int i = 0; int* pi = &i; is perfectly valid in unsafe code

Comment: Further addition: `fixed` is only rquired when the variable resides on the _managed_ heap. In interop scenarios, you also have the native Win32 heap, and all variables on it are fixed.